# Getting the data from rest api and print it in the form of table in the html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>


  <script>
var url  = "";
var xhr  = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', url, true)
xhr.onload = function () {
    var users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
    console.log(users);
    console.log(typeof users)
        console.table(users);
    } else {
        console.error(users);
    }
}
xhr.send(null);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**i want to get the restapi data and print in the form of table on my HTML page instead of console  .After coming out of script tag  the scope of my object is being lost 
help me to print the data on the html page
thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
       <table>
           <tr id="user"></tr>
       </table>

      <script>
    var url  = "";
    var xhr  = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('GET', url, true)
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
        console.log(users);
        for(var i = 0; i < user.length;i++){
          var node = document.createElement("td");
          var textnode = document.createTextNode(user[i]);
          node.appendChild(textnode);
          document.getElementById("user").appendChild(node);
        }

    }
    xhr.send(null);
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

first of all your response data should come as an array, then using for loop iterate response data, In HTML create on   give id for tr.
inside for loop create a node as TD and append your TD, finally call that id.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Like This...**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="myTable">
      <th>
        <td>heading</td>
        <td>heading</td>
      </th>

    </table>

  <script>
var url  = "";
var xhr  = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', url, true)
xhr.onload = function () {
    var users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {

    for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            var row = table.insertRow(0);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell1.innerHTML = users[i].value1;
            cell2.innerHTML = users[i].value2;
    }
    } else {
        console.error(users);
    }
}
xhr.send(null);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="f5buddytable"></div>

  <script>
        var url  = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=500";
        var xhr  = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open('GET', url, true)
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
             var table ="<table border='1'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Contact</th></tr>";
            var tr = "";
            var tableend = "</table>";
                var name,email,phone;
                for (var i = 0; i < users.results.length; i++) {
                   name = users.results[i]['name']['title']+' '+users.results[i]['name']['first'];
                   email = users.results[i]['email'];
                   phone = users.results[i]['phone'];

                   tr += "<tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+email+"</td><td>"+phone+"</td></tr>"; 

                }
              var finaltable =  table+tr+tableend; 
                document.getElementById('f5buddytable').innerHTML = finaltable;
           /* console.log(users);
            console.log(typeof users)
                console.table(users);*/
            } else {
                console.error(users);
            }
        }
        xhr.send(null);
    </script>
  </body>
```